# Snowflake task_history error codes and description

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to debug a Snowflake task which calls a SP and the task_history view under information_schema shows state as failed, error_code 000612 and error_description "Result not found". I tried searching for documentation around these error codes but didn't find anything. What does one interprets these codes/description?

Comment: This requires more investigation from Snowflake side, so it is probably better to open a support case.

Comment: I have not found any official reference. I usually did into the JDBC or Python Connector source code in github. For example: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/ErrorCode.java